# Extension of inequality of measures on a semiring to the $\sigma$-algebra generated

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I have a semiring $H$ over a set $X$, $\sigma(H)$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $H$ and two measures $\mu, \upsilon:\sigma(H) \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ such that $\upsilon\mid_{H}$ is $\sigma$-finite and
\begin{align*}
\mu(A) \leq \upsilon(A), \quad \forall A \in H.
\end{align*}

I want to prove $\mu(A) \leq \upsilon(A)$ for all $A \in \sigma(H)$. So far I think I can define a sequence $\{E_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq H$ for a given $A \in \sigma(H)$ such that $\{E_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $A$ and
$$
\mu(A) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(E_i) \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \upsilon(E_i) = \mu(A).
$$

Such sequence would be defined using the fact that $\upsilon\mid_{H}$ is $\sigma$-finite.

I don't really think it is correct as I don't know if I can stablish the equality of limits and I'm not using the fact that the elements of the sequence have finite measure under $\upsilon$.